# How to install and test IPA file in Windows machine if I don't have real iPhone device

Tags: manual-testing, mobile, ios

I want to test IPA file(iOS app) but I don't have real iOS device, only I have IPA file.

How can I test it from my windows machine, by using some third party tool like Simulator?

Answer (score 1):

Only with the Windows machine, we cannot the iPhone Emulator. Either you have to connect to any of the remote Mac machine or the Mac Server.

And one more thing is iOS Testing is not supported in the Windows if you are using Visual Studio or VS code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test an iOS device without a Mac laptop/desktop. They are extremely restrictive in who can access and develop for their devices. There are no emulators that can help you with this. You must have XCode, and the XCUITest toolset contained within that code library, to be allowed to programmatically interact with iOS devices.